# Object reference not set exception despite reference being set

Tags: .net, arrays, string, exception, split

I'm programming a multiplayer FPS game in C# currently, and something weird is happening with the client: a user that sends a shooting packet of a new bullet causes the server to broadcast the new bullet packet to all users connected, but this exception is being thrown:

[image]

See line 94: I try to access the last part of the packet data, split by `!`, which contains the position of the cursor the bullet has to be shot to.

I try to access it, and the "object reference not set" exception is thrown, even though you can clearly see that `Parts[2]` is defined (look at the debug details, it's`"612,311"`, and yet when I try to access it, this exception is thrown).

Why doesn't it work, then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the application multithreaded? Is something else receiving that same message that could be modifying it, or could whatever sends the message be modifying it before receivers process it? Is `Message` a member variable in a class that could be resetting its value?

What you're seeing appears impossible. When that happens, it's often impossible in a single-threaded application but possible when multiple threads are accessing the same variables.

Comment: Thanks, I solved it anyway by correcting the format of the server packet sending!